# Why does my battery still show that its damaged after replacing it

Tags: samsung, battery-life, google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I have a Samsung Galaxy s10 that I recently had to replace the non-removable battery. The original was needing to be charged every 2 hours! I went on Samsung Members app and did a diagnostic test which confirmed that I did indeed need a new battery. The exact results were "Battery Status: ACTION REQUIRED battery life weak. Replace because battery is old or in bad condition." So I had someone replace the battery. It's working alot better however when I did the diagnostic test again I got the same results! Also Google sent me a notification to "finish setting up my new device" and gave me the restore your contacts option etc like when you get a brand new phone and need to connect your Google acct for the first time. Is this normal after replacing battery?

Comment: You could try to wipe data and cache of the Samsung members app and if this doesn't help factory reset the phone.